# Why are all the movie clips I import into the compositor not working?

Tags: compositing-nodes, import, transparency, video, movie-clip-editor

When I import a movie clip into the compositor in blender, it shows up in the backdrop as completely transparent, showing the black and grey tile pattern to signify a transparent image. Anybody know why this might be happening? Any help would be greatly appreciated. I've attached the blend file below. (Ignore all the nodes that aren't connected to the viewer node. I'm only concerned with the movie clip connected to the viewer node)
[image]

Comment: When I load a file into any of the movie clip nodes, it is shown correctly. Is your file perhaps invalid? How did you create the  movie file.

Comment: It's an mp4 file I downloaded. Does blender only take avi?

Comment: No, Blender supports a multitude of formats, have you tried opening it in the [movie clip editor](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/movie_clip_editor/introduction.html) to check it?

Answer (score 2):

I had the frame range set to the wrong set of frames.